# How simulate click on button Class "input-button blue" without id

Tags: javascript, html

How do I simulate a click on this button using JavaScript

I tried `document.querySelector('.button.input-button.blue').click();` but it isn't working.

```js
document.querySelector('.button.input-button.blue').click();
```

```html
<div class="page-text" style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 310px; right: 10px; text-align: center;">
  <span style="font-size:24px;letter-spacing:1px;">138</span>
  <span style="font-size:20px;letter-spacing:1px;">1</span>
  <span style="font-size:24px;letter-spacing:1px;">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>
  <span style="font-size:24px;letter-spacing:1px;">138</span>
  <span style="font-size:20px;letter-spacing:1px;">3</span>
</div>

<button class="input-button blue" style="position: absolute; top: 244px; right: 30px; width: 187px;">Fill</button>

<button class="input-button red" style="position: absolute; top: 244px; left: 330px; width: 187px;">Sell</button>
```

I expect a click on "button blue"

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong, it should be something like this `document.querySelector('.input-button.blue')`

You can check querySelector docs from [MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and the quick summary is listed below.

1. You can use `.` to denote a class selector i.e. select an element with a certain class.
2. You can use `#` to select an element with an ID
3. When selecting elements by tag name e.g. `button`, the element name isn't preceded by anything

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('.input-button.blue');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  console.log('Button clicked');
})
btn.click();
```

```html
<div class="page-text" style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 310px; right: 10px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:24px;letter-spacing:1px;">138</span><span style="font-size:20px;letter-spacing:1px;">1</span><span style="font-size:24px;letter-spacing:1px;">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span><span style="font-size:24px;letter-spacing:1px;">138</span><span style="font-size:20px;letter-spacing:1px;">3</span></div>
<button class="input-button blue" style="position: absolute; top: 244px; right: 30px; width: 187px;">Fill</button>
<button class="input-button red" style="position: absolute; top: 244px; left: 330px; width: 187px;">Sell</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems here:

1. `.click()` is not a valid event listener, use `.onclick = function(){};` or `addEventListener`
2. `.button.input-button.blue` doesn't exist. I think what you actually mean is `button.input-button.blue`

`.button.input-button.blue` = `{class} .button {class} .input-button {class} .blue`

`button.input-button.blue` = `{element} button {class} .input-button {class} .blue`

https://codepen.io/StudioKonKon/pen/QzdoxY

```js
// Get the element node
var blue_button = document.querySelector('button.input-button.blue');

// Add event listener
blue_button.addEventListener(
   "click",
   function() {  console.log("Hello world"); },
   false
)

// Simulate use click
blue_button.click();
```

```html
<div class="page-text" style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 310px; right: 10px; text-align: center;">
  <span style="font-size:24px;letter-spacing:1px;">138</span>
  <span style="font-size:20px;letter-spacing:1px;">1</span>
  <span style="font-size:24px;letter-spacing:1px;">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>
  <span style="font-size:24px;letter-spacing:1px;">138</span>
  <span style="font-size:20px;letter-spacing:1px;">3</span>
</div>

<button class="input-button blue" style="position: absolute; top: 244px; right: 30px; width: 187px;">Fill</button>

<button class="input-button red" style="position: absolute; top: 244px; left: 330px; width: 187px;">Sell</button>
```